# How to convert sorted array to a BST?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search-tree

I'm struggling to get my desired output below. This is what I have done so far, and I think I'm close to being done.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sortedArrayBST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        try {

            if (n <= 0) {
                input.close();
            }

            int m = input.nextInt();
            if (m <= 0) {
                input.close();
            }

            int[] s = new int[n];
            int[] w = new int[m];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                s[i] = input.nextInt();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                w[i] = input.nextInt();
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        }
    }

    public static class TreeNode {
        int val;
        TreeNode left;
        TreeNode right;
        TreeNode parent;

        TreeNode(int x) {
            val = x;
        }
    }

    public static TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] num) {
        if (num == null || num.length == 0)
            return null;

        int start = 0, end = num.length - 1;

        TreeNode root = buildTree(num, start, end);

        return root;
    }

    public static TreeNode buildTree(int[] num, int start, int end) {

        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }

        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(num[mid]);

        node.left = buildTree(num, start, mid - 1);
        node.right = buildTree(num, mid + 1, end);

        return node;
    }
}
```

I have to take user input such as:

```
4 // denotes number of elements in array S, variable n.
2 // number of elements in array W, variable m.
0  // 0, 25, 33, 77 are in S.
25
33
77
19 // 19 and 40 are in W. 
40
```

Those numbers represent the sentence positions, so the ends of each sentence. 
The output is

```
2 // 2 words of interest found, this value is always the same as W above
1 25 // start of the sentence with 1st occurrence of word of interest (end      of previous sentence + 1) and end of the sentence (aka ".")
34 77 // so the previous sentence before this ended at position 33, so the next sentence started at 34, and it ends at 77.
```

IDK how to get this using a sorted array to a BST.

Comment: `I'm struggling to get my desired output` What is your desired output?

Comment: The bit at the bottom starting with 2.

Comment: The code you've posted looks ok to me and should print out 25(root),0(left), 33(right). Does it not?

Comment: It does yes, but that's just for my reference as I was working through things. Not what I actually need.

Comment: Please update your question/code with where you're facing the problem. As of now your question is really unclear.

Comment: why do you use `start + (end - start)/2` ? you may simply use `(start + end)/2`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think what you're looking for, is a way to traverse the `bst` you constructed to print the output in the given format.

If that is the case, you can do an `inorder traversal` of the tree to achieve that.(Although, having a sorted array, constructing a bst out of it and then printing the bst in a sorted order is kind of an overkill don't you think?)

```
static boolean flag = false;
public static void inorderTraverse(TreeNode root){
    if(root == null) return;
    inorderTraverse(root.left);
    if(flag){
        System.out.print(root.val);
        System.out.print("\n");
        flag = false;
    }
    else{ 
        flag = true;
        System.out.print(root.val + 1 + " ");
    }
    inorderTraverse(root.right);
}
```